# Getting duplicates in my oracle select query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

Following is my Oracle select query for the result, but I'm getting duplicates which I don`t need. I think it's hard to find for others,please give it a try.

```
SELECT I.EID                         EID,
       I.WT                          Title,
       I.RID                         RID,
       I.FORMNAME                    STAGENAME,
       I.FORMS                       STATUS,
       I.INPT                        Projects,
       To_char(I.DVDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DVDD,
       CASE
         WHEN B.SID = 2
              AND B.DID = 2 THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.DVDD
         ELSE NULL
       END                           DEVLAPSEDAYS,
       To_char(I.MDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  MDD,
       CASE
         WHEN B.SID = 2
              AND B.DID = 2 THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.MDD
         ELSE NULL
       END                           MONITORLAPSEDAYS,
       L.LDEID                       LEADEID
FROM   table1 I,
       table2 F,
       table3 B,
       table4 L
WHERE  I.ACTIVEFLG = 1
       AND I.LATESTFLG = 1
       AND I.FORMSTATUS IN ( 1, 3 )
       AND I.UNIQUEID = F.UNIQUEID
       AND B.SID = 2
       AND B.DID IN ( 2, 3 )
       AND ( F.EVENTDATE > I.DVDD
              OR F.EVENTDATE > I.MDD )
       AND ( ( Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.DVDD ) > 2
              OR ( Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.MDD ) > 2 )
       AND F.LINKID = B.LINKID
       AND I.FORMSTAGENAME IN ( 'Develop', 'Monitor' )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best I do with this kind of information is to tell you to group your entire query:

```
   GROUP BY I.EID,I.WT,I.RID,I.FORMNAME,I.FORMS,I.INPT,
   To_char(I.DVDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DVDD,
   CASE
     WHEN B.SID = 2
          AND B.DID = 2 THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.DVDD
     ELSE NULL
   END,
   To_char(I.MDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  MDD,
   CASE
     WHEN B.SID = 2
          AND B.DID = 2 THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.MDD
     ELSE NULL
   END,
   L.LDEID
```

Comment: there is a cartesian product in the OP's SQL causing duplicate rows.

Answer (score 2):

You are not linking `TABLE4` (aliased as `L`)to any of the other tables in your list thereby creating a cartesian product.
This is likely generating your duplicate records.

Join `TABLE4` to one of the other tables and you should be good to go.

See Cartesian Product in: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/queries006.htm

This is also a good reason for using the SQL-92 syntax over the old SQL-96. It forces you to specify your table joins explicitly.

I have rewritten your query using SQL-92 you only need to insert the join condition for TABLE4 and it should work for you.

Hope it helps...

```
SELECT I.EID                         EID,
       I.WT                          Title,
       I.RID                         RID,
       I.FORMNAME                    STAGENAME,
       I.FORMS                       STATUS,
       I.INPT                        Projects,
       To_char(I.DVDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY') DVDD,
       (CASE
           WHEN B.SID = 2
            AND B.DID = 2 
           THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.DVDD
           ELSE NULL
        END)                         DEVLAPSEDAYS,
       To_char(I.MDD, 'DD/MM/YYYY')  MDD,
       (CASE
         WHEN B.SID = 2
          AND B.DID = 2 
         THEN Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.MDD
         ELSE NULL
        END)                         MONITORLAPSEDAYS,
       L.LDEID                       LEADEID
  FROM table1 I
 INNER JOIN table2 F ON (I.UNIQUEID = F.UNIQUEID)
 INNER JOIN table3 B ON (F.LINKID = B.LINKID)
 INNER JOIN table4 L ON (<insert join clause here>)
 WHERE I.ACTIVEFLG = 1
   AND I.LATESTFLG = 1
   AND I.FORMSTATUS IN ( 1, 3 )
   AND B.SID = 2
   AND B.DID IN ( 2, 3 )
   AND ( F.EVENTDATE > I.DVDD OR F.EVENTDATE > I.MDD )
   AND ( ( Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.DVDD ) > 2 OR ( Trunc(F.EVENTDATE) - I.MDD ) > 2 )
   AND I.FORMSTAGENAME IN ( 'Develop', 'Monitor' )
```

Comment: :Thanks for the reply,Yeah i forgot to include one more join condition,I included it,but I don`t get any record now.

Comment: Remove the where clause restrictions (not the joins!) one by one until you find the restriction that is preventing any records from being returned.

Comment: Ollie:I tried that way,when I removed the condition->((TRUNC(F.EVENTDATE)-I.DVDD) >2 OR (TRUNC(F.EVENTDATE)-I.MDD) >2 )...I got few records...Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @palak, I'm afraid the investigation will be down to you, it is all about your data so there is little I can do to help you investigate. Sorry :-(